# Launch any maps app on Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, maps

I want to create an `Intent` in my Android app that launches a map application with a specified address in response to the user clicking on the button. It is straightforward enough to do this with Google Maps, as is explained [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/android-intents).

However, I was wondering what the correct way to do this would be in order to launch *any* maps application **(i.e., not necessarily Google Maps)**. This way, if the user prefers a different maps application, it would open in their app of choice instead.

For example, to launch the user's preferred calendar application, one sends an `Intent` to `com.android.calendar`, and it opens whichever calendar application is the default, not necessarily Google Calendar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `geo:` URI, as stated [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common#ViewMap). Disappointingly, this does not provide a mechanism for launching directly into turn-by-turn navigation.